# 'Directory not found for option '-F/Users/admin/xcreds/Carthage/Build/Mac'

Tags: xcode, carthage

I am trying to build [Xcreds](https://github.com/twocanoes/xcreds/blob/main/build_resources/buildscripts/build.sh) using Xcode. The build completes successfully, but I still receive this error message:

```
Directory not found for option '-F/Users/admin/xcreds/Carthage/Build/Mac'`.
```

The path specified in the error exists.

Carthage is installed.

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
User ~ % which carthage
/usr/local/bin/carthage
User ~ % carthage version
0.39.0
```

I've run an update inside the Xcreds project path where the Cartfile is located using

```
carthage update --platform macOS
```

I cannot delete the Framework Search Paths since they are required for the build

Comment: `-F/Users/admin` seems very odd.

Comment: I just used `admin` as a placeholder for my actual computer username